# iOS PhoneGap Plugins stop working after adding CocoonJS iOS WebView+ Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cocoonjs

Like the title says. Adding CocoonJS iOS WebView+ plugin to my Cordova PhoneGap project stops it from loading and running plugins.

I also tried it with an empty project and it also did not work.

Here is how I am adding the CocoonJS plugin:

```
cocoonjs plugin add com.ludei.ios.webview.plus
```

I tried it with the following plugins:

```
com.google.cordova.admob 1.1.1 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
com.ludei.ios.webview.plus 1.0.4 "Webview+"
com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio 1.1.4 "LowLatencyAudio"
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.7 "SocialSharing"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.2 "Camera"
```

None of them worked.

For SocialSharing, the initialization function *does* get called. But none of the other plugin functions are called.

For the rest of the plugins, even the initialization functions are not called.

After comparing a project with WebView+ and without, it seems the place it calls the plugin initializations from is in CordovaLib.xcodeproj/Classes/Cleaver/CDViewController.m, on line 669, it tries to load the plugins by checking if the url scheme is for a PhoneGap app:

(

```
BOOL)webView:(UIWebView)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* url = [request URL];

    /* Execute any commands queued with cordova.exec() on the JS side.
    The part of the URL after gap:// is irrelevant. */ 
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"]) 
    { 
        [commandQueue fetchCommandsFromJs]; // The delegate is called asynchronously in this case, so we don't have to use // flushCommandQueueWithDelayedJs (setTimeout(0)) as we do with hash changes. 
        [commandQueue executePending]; 
        return NO; 
    }
...
}
```

On my PhoenGap project without CocoonJS, `theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest` gets called 3 times. The last time with `@"gap://ready"`.

It then enters that part of the code and loads all the plugins.

With the CocoonJS, `theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest` only gets called once, and never with the `@"gap://ready"`. So none of the plugins ever get initialized.

On the CocoonJS site they seem to indicate that you *can* use PhoneGap plugins with WebView+.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is the official answer: they do not support phonegap plugins.

> Hello,
>
> Sorry for the late response, and for the bad news. We are not
>   compatible with PhoneGap Plugins yet. In addition, I don't know if we
>   will in the near future.
>
> Regards.

http://support.ludei.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201575145-iOS-PhoneGap-Plugins-not-loading-after-adding-CocoonJs-plugin